# If I email something to myself on a private server, can it be intercepted?

Tags: security, email-server

My friend is running an email service on their own private server. It's not rented in any way, they own the hardware, it is 100% self-contained. I don't really understand much about it, but along with others I have an email address there and use it for email.

If I log into the webmail portal and then email myself a note, is there any way it can be intercepted by an outside entity? Does my email ever leave the server into the wild web if I'm just messaging myself? Aside from a yes or no answer, I'd also like explanations if possible.

Comment: If you want to email yourself a note that only you can read, end-to-end encryption is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't know anything about the software being used to create the email serivce or the webmail portal, but the answer is most likely that it doesn't leave the server.

When you send an email via Webmail, the web application will either use a local mail service, or be configured to use an SMTP server to send that email.

If Webmail and the email system are running on the same system then it's highly likely** that the local mail service will handle the email you just sent (even if webmail is using SMTP). If that's the case, and you're emailing an address which is hosted on the same system, then the message should just be placed directly in your mailbox and never leave that system.

**It's entirely possible for the Webmail application to send via an external SMTP service, which would cause the emails to go out to the Internet, then work their way back to your mailbox, but that would be a very unusual setup for a private mail server.

Whether someone could hack into the server and access all your email data that way is another issue though.

You also need to make sure the Webmail application is accessed over HTTPS if it's the content of the message you are concerned about. If you use HTTP, then the message could be intercepted in the HTTP traffic when you are writing it.